# Parallel Trend assumption in DiD

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference

This assumption should rule out the concern of selection bias, right? For example, I am looking at the effect of increasing police presence on crimes. The government decided to put more police in certain areas. Of course, the police will be placed into cities with more violence. If 2 cities have similar trend in crime pre-treatment, I don't have to worry about the selection bias, right?

Comment: Do you only have two cities? Usually a city government augments its patrol staffing based upon need, which is usually in response to upticks in overall crime reporting.

Comment: No, not necessarily two cities. Maybe multiple cities. The control group will be likely to have less crime than the treated group. Basically, someone was commenting on a paper that the treatment is "endogeneous" because we expect cities with treatment is more prone to crime and thus DiD is not accurate, but I thought otherwise, so I just want to be sure I wasn't crazy.

Comment: Did the paper demonstrate, to some degree, parallel trends? Also, it depends on the cities that were sampled. Are nearly all the treated cities the “high crime” jurisdictions?

Comment: Yes, they had some evidence for parallel trend. What do you mean by depending on the cities that were sampled? What happens if all nearly the treated cities are in the high-crime jurisdiction?

Comment: Did they sample all cities in a particular region? Surely some of the cities in the sample were also high in crime but didn’t receive the additional manpower, or maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/difference-difference-estimation), the parallel trend assumption does not require that the pre-treatment response trends are "similar" between the two groups. They need to be parallel in time, whatever your expression of trend is (usually linear). Of course, if the time-trends are *equal* (note: "similar" is too imprecise) they are, of course parallel. See figure 1 from link below.

Selection bias is a whole other can of worms. The point of selection bias is that it affects observable trends. As a consequence the *data* do not tell you if there's bias, rather the *design* does. It is in fact possible for selection bias to *cause* non-parallel time-trends to *be* parallel. Consider comparing police forces in municipalities between two regions; say you are curious if there are protocols implemented for investigating homicide. If you only sample units of a certain size, you guarantee the level of crime has some degree of preparedness for particular issues, notably murder. But if one states comprises mostly smaller municipalities where forces do not have protocols since the incidence is much lower, your design has an incorrect inference that the two groups are "similar" (equal, parallel, or otherwise).

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the example you provided about selection bias. What is the treatment here? Or is there no treatment whatsoever and I'm just comparing the degree of preparedness between the two cities' police forces? And what are they paralleling? In terms of preparedness?

Comment: @Rainroad the example is of a biased design, irrespective of whatever intervention is proposed. The "parallel" regards time trends in a pre-intervention era.